# Magento2 EE with Solr5

Tags: magento2, magento-enterprise, solr

I am trying to configure magento2 EE 2.0.2 with Solr v5.4.1 (latest), although the magento2 documentation shows that how to setup Solr 4.10.4 as an example.

I was wondering if magento2 EE is only compatible with Solr4 only or will it support Solr5 as well ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Magento_Solr depends on a old Solarium version (3.3.0) which does not support Solr5 (see: https://github.com/solariumphp/solarium/issues/326).

So it definitely does not work with Solr5 out of the box.